# Changing the location of git installation on linux

Tags: linux, git, redhat

I apologize if this seems basic but I'm new to linux and not really sure how to proceed. My current git version is 1.7.1 and is located in /usr/bin/git but a newer version of git (1.8) is now available in /usr/src/git/bin/git. How do I make git use this version by default as opposed to the 1.7.1 version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make sure to call the right executable.  This can ben done by explicitly calling `/usr/src/git/bin/git` instead of `git`.  Of course this would be annoying to type all the time, so you can either make `git` an alias for that path by adding the line

```
alias git=/usr/src/git/bin/git
```

to your `.bashrc`, or add the directory `/usr/src/git/bin` to your binary search path by adding the line

```
export PATH="/usr/src/git/bin:$PATH"
```

To test that the other git installation searches for the core binaries in the right place, you can check the output of `git --exec-path`.