# for npm install from folder gives git error for wikimedia packages despite dependencies already being installed (shared hosting)

Tags: linux, git, npm-install, web-hosting, parsoid

Npm install on wikimedia packages (parsoid, restbase, plus service-runner and limitation) fails with a git error, despite having copied the source files in advance, and running

`npm install <folder>`
or
`npm install` from the actual folder, which has a package.json
or

`npm install -g --only=prod --verbose limitation`

The dependencies giving errors are sometimes direct dependencies, sometimes dependencies of dependencies.

**Setup**
 - linux / CentrOS 6

- git installed by ISP on shared host, git re-install fails
- no admin rights since shared hosting
- node 11.12.0, npm 6.9.0
- only wikimedia packages fail, but not all wikimedia packages

**Steps tried**
 - installing only production dependencies

- `npm cache verify` plus deleting relevant node_module and .npm folders before install
- editing package.json to replace git link for dependencies with just the versions, eg for kad `2.5.1`
- latest version of npm and node
- reinstall of node/nvm/npm
- also failed with node v11.11.0
- using npm list to check any dependency issues and fix in advance
- git fix by swapping to http or git protocols failed with same error

**Dependencies being looked for include**

- pegjs
- kad
- content-type

**Example error log: limitation package**
(3 dependencies, including bluebird, kad, readable-stream)

`135 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream 17ms (from cache)
136 silly pacote range manifest for readable-stream@^2.0.5 fetched in 25ms
137 silly resolveWithNewModule readable-stream@2.3.6 checking installable status
138 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for kad@git+https://github.com/wikimedia/kad.git#master Error while executing:
138 silly fetchPackageMetaData /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin/git ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/wikimedia/kad.git
138 silly fetchPackageMetaData
138 silly fetchPackageMetaData fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
138 silly fetchPackageMetaData
138 silly fetchPackageMetaData exited with error code: 128
139 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
140 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 4749ms
141 verbose stack Error: exited with error code: 128
141 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/mousey/.nvm/.nvm/versions/node/v11.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/util/finished.js:12:19)
141 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
141 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:988:16)
141 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
142 verbose cwd /home/mousey/.nvm/.nvm/versions/node/v11.12.0/lib/node_modules
143 verbose Linux 2.6.32-896.16.1.lve1.4.54.el6.x86_64
144 verbose argv "/home/mousey/.nvm/.nvm/versions/node/v11.12.0/bin/node" "/home/mousey/.nvm/.nvm/versions/node/v11.12.0/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "--save" "--verbose" "--only=prod" "service-runner"
145 verbose node v11.12.0
146 verbose npm  v6.9.0
147 error Error while executing:
147 error /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin/git ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/wikimedia/kad.git
147 error
147 error fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
147 error
147 error exited with error code: 128
148 verbose exit [ 1, true ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git path was set incorrectly, causing the git error:

`Unable to find remote helper for 'https'`

[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728941/changing-the-location-of-git-installation-on-linux).

`git --exec-path` revealed the git problem

I still don't understand why git was needed when all files wre local and packages pulled from git were already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your .gitconfig file. There is a known issue in npm with git+http/ssh remotes.

```
  [url "https://github.com/"]
     insteadOf = git@github.com:
     insteadOf = git://github.com/
     insteadOf = git+https://github.com/
     insteadOf = git+ssh://git@github.com:
     insteadOf = ssh://git@github.com:
     insteadOf = ssh+https://git@github.com/
```

[Link for reference](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16980)

Comment: I've tried similar already, still the same git error. It should not need git at all given that all dependencies are already installed AND in a local directory. (Although I would accept an answer that fixes git, it should not be necessary to use it).